# Converting to comment multiple times leaves behind undelete votes

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-abilities, convert-to-comment

I mangled a convert to comment earlier and needed to undelete the post so I could redo it. When the post was converted a second time, I noticed it suddenly had a single undelete vote (it said "undelete (1)" on the link, and showed up in the 10k list). When I undeleted and converted it again it had two votes, and so on:

[image]

If I delete normally it works fine; it's only converting to comment (and probably edit, although I didn't try) more than once that leaves behind undelete votes

Comment: Alternatively, you're secretly building up an army of Nega-Mrozeks by undeleting them from non-existence, soon able to topple the world and conquer it under the banner of an angry glaring chess piece. This is no bug report, but a preview of the future's madness under your iron rule!

Comment: @Grace I wish I could get this to work on close votes instead of undelete votes; I would make every closed post say I voted to close it five times

Comment: I'm also kind of curious why the space between revision blocks gets bigger as you go up the list

Comment: I don't believe this actually happens.

Comment: Not until we break out some doughnuts

Comment: Or at the very least set up some Earl Grey for our guests

Comment: Don't you think they'd like some cucumber sandwiches as well?

Comment: What a marvellous idea! Summon the chef to prepare the breadknife.

Comment: We mustn't forget to include the jar jam to swill in our teas

Comment: Yes! We can pretend we are all Leo Tolstoys and marvel at the wonder of life

Comment: I don't believe this actually happens.

Comment: I don't believe this actually happens.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: I now believe this actually happens.

Comment: @Wont Well, you appear to be outvoted 7-1

Comment: So... get it right the first time. ;)

Comment: Notice this also works for any post that gets deleted, then undeleted to convert to comment. I haven't tried with delete-undelete-delete proper.

Comment: @jcolebrand Interesting; I wouldn't have expected that. It doesn't happen with delete/undelete/delete

Comment: @Michael ~ Yeah, I had that case the other day where I had to undelete a post that was deleted by owner to make it a comment (it added context to the discussion, so it needed to be a comment) and I noticed what you posted and didn't think anything of it, and when you said this I thought "better chirp up"

Comment: I noticed some weird behavior as a result of Will's testing, and reported it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116017/negative-number-of-votes-needed-to-undelete-an-answer).

Comment: @ಠ_ಠWon't I should flag you, but you'd just delete it off the queue. ;)

Comment: @muntoo: For what?  Was testing.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠWon't That's what you want us to think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build. There is a vote cleanup function for old votes that wasn't running on this code path...and is now.