# Can one person have two votes to delete?

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, deleted-answers

The deleted answer to https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12100/732 has four delete votes, but two of them are from the same person.

How did that happen?

Screenshot

---

[image]

Comment: Most of us can't see deleted answers. Can you post a screenshot of: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/12100/revisions ?

Comment: PS: Weirder things: http://i.stack.imgur.com/L4ywm.png

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ [Please](http://i.stack.imgur.com/E5X8p.png)

Comment: @Fezziwig Link or didn't happen.

Comment: Haha so basically every time you vote to delete and then vote to undelete, it appends your name to the list of deleters without checking if you're there already?

Comment: @animuson We are mods. We tend to break things.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94627/converting-to-comment-multiple-times-leaves-behind-undelete-votes

Comment: Similar question: Can the same user vote to close a question twice?

Comment: Delete vote is coming from ordinary members, but from the posted screenshots, it was deleted by moderator who need no "votes" - just semantics though.

Comment: Seen this before when a normal user casts a close vote, then becomes mod and casts a definitive close vote. Maybe the same thing for deleting here?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ screenshot up

Comment: @ShmuelBrill This could be a bug, but it only takes 3 votes to delete posts anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this page: [Converting to comment multiple times leaves behind undelete votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94627/converting-to-comment-multiple-times-leaves-behind-undelete-votes)

```
This will be fixed in the next build. 
There is a vote cleanup function for 
old votes that wasn't running on this  
code path...and is now.

Nick Craver
```

Comment: Huh, yeah, that's fixed and about undelete votes, not delete votes.

Comment: The answer wasn't converted to a comment, neither was it a mod who had the two delete votes.

Comment: I noticed that it's fixed