# Negative number of votes needed to undelete an answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-undelete

I know Will was using his answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94627/converting-to-comment-multiple-times-leaves-behind-undelete-votes) for testing, but I still think this is a bit odd:

[image: tooltip says "-5 more vote(s) needed to undelete this answer"]

I tried voting to undelete, but it just gave me the "nice try puny mortal, this was deleted by a **mod**" error popup.

Comment: The bug is the undelete votes are never cleared, as I answered [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215874/152859)

Comment: since 2011? nice... let me see what I can do...

Comment: @m0sa more likely since the beginning of Stack Overflow, or at least undelete votes mechanism, just someone reported it on 2011. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215875/156631), the actual bug was that undelete votes did not get cleared after a post was deleted by a scheduled task (by the Community user).

This was fixed in build rev `2014.1.13.1298` (for posts auto-deleted after that date).

Comment: Did you mean 2014.1.13.1298? Or was it fixed year ago? ;-)

Comment: Well, I'm proud of you for manually writing that every time instead of copy&paste from your logs. (which I assume contain such info :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard now I feel like being in school again... I've always had issues with adding the correct date to notes in January... with the difference that my _fail_ is now public :)

Comment: Yup... hope you at least sign checks with correct date! ;)

Answer (score 6):

This happens any time something gets more votes than should be possible. I wouldn't really call it a bug -- the bug is that that answer has 8 votes to undelete. The message is making the assumption that a post will never have more than 3 undelete votes, which is generally valid; you just found a remnant of a bug that temporarily allowed it