# "0 more votes are needed to undelete this post"

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, vote-to-undelete

I appear to have stumbled upon an odd question:

> [image: screenshot 1]
>
> [image: screenshot 2]

[Here is a link to the question (please don't vote to undelete it! keep it there so people can see it)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20620509/1223693)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The bug is that undelete votes are never cleared.

See in the [revisions list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20620509/revisions):

> [image]

There are indeed three undelete votes, and will be forever. :)

This also cause other weird looking bugs, like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191119/152859):

> [image]

Comment: Someone needs to build a bot to stop Community bot from taking over the site

Comment: **Post Deleted** by Community♦, Community♦, Community♦, Community♦, Community♦, Community♦

Comment: @Jamal luckily enough, delete votes do get cleared when the post is deleted. :)

Comment: found [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450854/object-does-not-work-as-link), fixing...

Comment: @m0sa wow, the OP there was really busy deleting and undeleting! How you plan to fix, if I might ask? :)

Comment: @m0sa from the lack of answer I understand that it turned out to be bigger bug than you thought?

Comment: @ShadowWizard [see](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216077/156631) thanks for the detective work!

Comment: @m0sa awesome, thanks!